# Moovweb: specify assets in images/folder via html?

Tags: moovweb

I know that its possible to reference the contents of your images folder using tritium.  I am however using the read() function to bring in an html snippet. Is there a way to specify images via that html snippet?
eg:

```
<img src='/moovweb_local_assets_/images/Logo150.png">' alt="1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about this but i can give you some trick.
Add any class or id to this img tag and add the src attribute and its url with the help of tritium. eg.,

html:

```
<img id="myImage" alt="1" />
```

tritium:

```
$$("#myImage"){
   attribute('src',asset('images/Logo150.png'));
}
```